# How to export a database's data to a new one(python/mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, django

lets say I have an old database in mysql and i want to export all of its data to a new mysql database with python(or Django). How can I do that? consider that the old database might not have some fields of some tables of the new database(for example there is a table called "product" in the old database, we have the same table in the new database but with an extra field called 'address'. so the old data base doesnt have the field address but the new one does). I just want to transfer the data, tables already exist in the new database

Comment: What about using a `pandas.DataFrame` to collect/store the old data and use the `.to_sql` method to push into the new table, with the argument `if_exists='append'`.

Comment: Does new and old databases are served by the same MySQL instance? different instances within the same OS instance? different instances within different OS instances which are cross-accessible? different instances within different OS instances which are not cross-accessible?

Comment: @Akina the data bases are in diffrent servers

Comment: @S3DEV thanks for your help, I will check out pandas

Comment: *the data bases are in diffrent servers* Check does [FEDERATED engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) is available on your servers.